# OP accepted my answer but deserves the credit

Tags: discussion, flags, accepted-answer, editing-help

The OP derived a solution based upon my answer. He graciously commented on me being a contribution to his solution, and updated his question to include his own solution. The OP's answer is a better solution than my answer. However the OP accepted my answer, instead of including his own and accepting it. As a poster, I also would want to fall on the safe side of accepting somebody else's answer than to possibly have the appearance of stealing credit by creating and accepting my own answer

Is it possible to flag (or edit) the post to have the OP's solution (which is included in the post) made into the accepted answer?

Comment: *"updated his question to include his own solution"* - They should instead post their solution as an _answer_ to their own question. Assuming you meant [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73479388/detect-u-shave-or-v-shape-in-data-series) their edit has already been rolled back and this explained to them.

Comment: No. Nothing can be converted _to_ an answer automatically. Answers also don't belong in the question. The best you can do is direct them to https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer and hope they take the hint, roll back, and post a proper answer. At the bare minimum, the answer should be removed from the question, but because you have <2k, it's probably better if you personally don't.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine wow, that rollback happened pretty quick.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine directing him is good idea. Thanks. Have you considered putting your comment as an answer? hint, hint :-)

Comment: The accepted answer is not necessarily the best answer anyway. We hope (and expect) that the highest voted answer is the best.

Answer (score 8):

No, the OP controls the accepted answer.

If they chose not to author their own answer and accept it (which is something they *can* do), then there's nothing anyone else could do to move the accepted answer somewhere else.

Comment: I sure there are ways of handling OPs who actually re-post a good answer as there own and accept it. Is there a process for encouraging overly humble OPs?

Comment: I mean if they *repost* an answer that exists somewhere else, that's plagiarism and that's both different and orthogonal to what you're bringing up.  In the sense of encouraging them, the *best* you could do is leave a comment.  If they take no action then you've done everything you could.